# Unable to catch RuntimeError raised due to closing asyncio event loop

Tags: python-asyncio, python-3.8, event-loop

I am writing a python script that uses signal_handler to capture SIGINT, SIGTSTP signals. The signal handler closes the event loop, which raises a RuntimeError. I'm trying to catch this error and display something else instead. My code is as follows:

```
async def signal_handler(self):
    try : 
        #perform some cleanup by executing some coroutines
        self.loop.stop()
    except RuntimeError as err:
        print('SIGINT or SIGTSTP raised')
        print("cleaning and exiting")
        sys.exit(0)
```

The output is as follows:

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "pipeline.py", line 69, in <module>
    pipeline(sys.argv[1], (lambda : sys.argv[2] if len(sys.argv)==3 else os.getcwd())())
  File "pipeline.py", line 9, in __init__
    self.main(link)
  File "pipeline.py", line 52, in main
    asyncio.run(video.get_file(obj.metadata['name']+"_v."+obj.default_video_stream[1], obj.default_video_stream[0]))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 614, in run_until_complete
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop stopped before Future completed.')
RuntimeError: Event loop stopped before Future completed.
```

From the output I can infer that

> self.loop.stop()

raised the RuntimeError.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## MRE

Let's start with a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we know we are on the same page:

```py
import asyncio
import signal
import sys


loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()

async def main():
    while True:
        print('Hey')
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)

async def _signal_handler():
    try:
        loop.stop()
    except RuntimeError as err:
        print('SIGINT or SIGTSTP raised')
        print("cleaning and exiting")
        sys.exit(1)

def signal_handler(*args):
    loop.create_task(_signal_handler())

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

This will print the following when SIGINT is received:

```py
Hey
Hey
Hey
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "73094030.py", line 26, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 614, in run_until_complete
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop stopped before Future completed.')
RuntimeError: Event loop stopped before Future completed.
```

## Problem

The error will be raised in `main()`. It happens because the loop is forced to exit before `asyncio.sleep()` task is finished.

## Solution

To solve this, we should *cancel* the task before exiting. Let's replace

```
loop.stop()
```

with

```py
tasks = asyncio.all_tasks(loop)
for task in tasks:
    task.cancel()
```

This still raises an exception:

```py
Hey
Hey
Hey
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "73094030.py", line 28, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError
```

But we have proceeded to change `RuntimeError` to `CancelledError` which is more descriptive. It also allows the running functions to run their `finally` blocks, freeing resources. The event loop will stop automatically after all the tasks finish.

Of course we now *except* to get a `CancelledException`. So let's add a `try/except` block to `main()`:

```py
async def main():
    try:
        while True:
            print('Hey')
            await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print('\nFunction stopped manually.')
```

Now we get no clutter:

```py
Hey
Hey
Hey
^C
Function stopped manually.
```

The final code looks like this:

```py
import asyncio
import signal
import sys


loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()

async def main():
    try:
        while True:
            print('Hey')
            await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
    except asyncio.CancelledError:
        print('\nFunction stopped manually.')


async def _signal_handler():
    try:
        tasks = asyncio.all_tasks(loop)
        for task in tasks:
            task.cancel()
    except RuntimeError as err:
        print('SIGINT or SIGTSTP raised')
        print("cleaning and exiting")
        sys.exit(1)

def signal_handler(*args):
    loop.create_task(_signal_handler())

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, helped me understand certain fundamental concepts.